Other Simpson’s Rule-like approximations
Today in my calc class we went over Simpson’s Rule and derived it from the quadratic.  In the same nature, I tried using sine curves in order to get a better approximation.  My questions are:

How would one derive this using sine waves?

What are the optimal functions to base the approximation on?



https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#See_also

The optimal functions to approximate a given function $f$ will depend on $f$. I don't think there's much else one can say, in such generality.
